# lwjgl application will occasionally not force quit on OS X

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've recently switched my render engine over completely from fixed-function to shader-based.  While most everything is working just fine, sometimes when I close an application, it will sit in the dock and will not quit.  Force quit does nothing, and when this happens I have to hold down the power button to shut down my computer, as the applications don't close at shutdown either.

I make sure to release all resources before closing the application.  I'm running OS X 10.9.4 and Java 1.6.0_65.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to be a simple memory leak.  I was creating an excessive number of vertex buffers and never releasing them.  I suppose this is another example of why you should always watch your memory allocations, even in Java.